# Android Canvas drawRect function doesn't show paint shadow

Tags: java, android, canvas, shadow

I am trying to use Android's onDraw function to draw rectangles and lines with shadows around them so they can be seen on a white backgrounds. I have my Paint set up to have a shadowlayer but there is no shadow when the lines are drawn.

Here is my code for the Paint:

```
paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setTextSize(m_textSize);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
Typeface font = Typeface.create("Times New Roman", Typeface.NORMAL);
paint.setTypeface(font);
paint.setShadowLayer(5, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, paint);
```

And here is my drawing code:

```
private void drawMark(Canvas c, float y, float size)
    {
    float x = (float) (getWidth()-5.0-size);
    c.drawRect(x, y, x + size, y + markHeight, paint);
    }
```

Is there something I am missing to make the shadow work for drawRect?

Please note that I am also using the canvas to draw text and the text does get the shadow effect, but shapes and lines do not.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shadows will only appear when you're drawing in software mode:

```
this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);
```

Comment: Does that need to be used on every draw? I already am calling that function in my above code when I create the Paint I need.

Comment: You've got LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE in the code you posted

Comment: That would do it. Thanks!